# Lifecycle React component, with instant loading component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

So, let talk about lifecycle of a component React.

I have my model file is name is `Firebase.js` inside I have all my methods can trigger my data.

`Firebase.js`

```js
export const getUserShare = () => {
  let arr = [];
  db.ref(`/music/${userID()}`).on("value", (snapshot, key) => {
    snapshot.forEach(items => {
      let element = items.val();
      arr.push(element);
    });
  });
  return arr;
};
```

And I have a `Profil.js` component and inside I import the method that I want (For this example `_getUserData()`)

On my component I set a state `arrSharing`, at the name of my method `_getUserData()` the output of this is an array with all my data.

`Profil.js` :

```js
this.state = {
      arrSharing: getUserShare()
};
```

The `Profil.js` is only accessible with my router or if you put the link on your browser.

Now I rendering the data in my render function like that :

```js
{this.state.arrSharing.map((items, i) => {
                    return (
                      <div key={i} className="share-music">
                        <h5 className="share-music__title">
                          {items.artiste} - {items.title}
                        </h5>
                        <p className="share-music__platform">
                          par {items.displayName} sur #{items.radio}
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    );
                  })}
```

Now running the application and if I go for the first time on the `Profil.js` component the data was not loaded, BUT if I go on another component and after I return on `Profil.js` the data was loaded.

The problem come from the component is not rendering for the first time. When I use `componentDidMount()` I have the same problem. And it's very problematic for my case.

Comment: You need to show how `arrSharing` is being updated.

Comment: I updated the post with the method who return my data, with the initial state :)

Comment: Yes it's updated, so when I use `console.log(this.state.arrSharing)` below the initial state, or in `componentDidMount()` I have all my data, but the render does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see there is a problem with asynchronous action handling.

Change your `getUserShare` method to accept callback:

```
export const getUserShare = (callback) => {
  db.ref(`/music/${userID()}`).on("value", (snapshot, key) => {
    const arrSharing = [];
    snapshot.forEach(items => {
      let element = items.val();
      arrSharing.push(element);
    });
    callback(arrSharing);
  });
};
```

Then do this in **Profile.js**:

```
this.state = {
  arrSharing: [],
}

componentDidMount() {
  getUserShare((arrSharing) => {
    this.setState({ arrSharing })
  })
}
```

Comment: I have this error : `snapshot.map is not a function` When running the component

Comment: Dude, you know god ? I think you look like him!

Comment: @Jonathan haha you made day :)